# Use Query result in ALTER statement (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to create a script to update passwords for a large number of users listed in a given table.

```
alter user FOO identified by FOOWORD;
```

I can call the usernames via the following statement:

```
select owner from usertable_verson where rownum = 1
```

Is there a way to combine these two statements, so that the alter user command works for each result of the select command?

The eventual goal is to create a loop for each username in the selected column, and apply the password change to each.

Answer (score 2):

you can do this via [dynamic SQL](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/executeimmediate_statement.htm#i33888)
smth like this:

```
begin
  for rc in (select owner from usertable_verson) loop
    execute immediate 'alter user '||rc.owner||' identified by FOOWORD'; 
  end loop;
end;
```